# Как увеличить место /tmpfs/ для контейнеров

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Добрый вечер!

Сделал docker-compose up для существующего проекта.

Поднялись все контейнеры. Начал заливать бэкап базы.

И уперся в нехватку места. Раздел tmpfs ограничен 983М для любых контейнеров. Как увеличить место в этом разделе?

Comment: Как вы добавили userland tmpfs в контейнерах и каким директориям это соответствует?

Comment: Для проекта автоматом поставился следующий контейнер "wodby/drupal-mariadb". БД находится в /var/lib/mysql (раздел tmpfs). df - h говорит что место для раздела 983 М.

Comment: Разобрался. Нужно было увеличить память для машины.